# How to decrypt a string in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, aes

I am currently working on a project that takes incoming messages from Amazons SQS (Simple Queue Service).

I have established the connection to the SQS service and receiving messages.

The receiving message is in the following format:

```
   { MessageId: '124a42b-657d-481d-348f-ddd9b8d8b143b',
  ReceiptHandle: 'AQEBSSVzlCbqsSUQ3E.....',
  MD5OfBody: '7ba46c7c8874fc6d0c4a141a2d3d4d5a721',
  Body: '10987235@PUBLISH;aSeIgjS78Iy4KRZHSeAy43...' }
```

The Message Body is encrypted, I been given the password to decrypt it.

My question is how do I decrypt the message Body in nodeJS?

Any examples would be much appreciated!

UPDATE:

Here is a copy of my code so far:

```
        const Consumer = require('sqs-consumer');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");
const unzipper = require('unzipper');

const app = Consumer.create({
  queueUrl: 'https://sqs.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/QueueName',
  handleMessage: (message, done) => {

    saveToFile(message.Body)
      .then(() => {
        return unzipFile();
      })
      .then((success) => {
        // read content of XML file and save to DB
        console.log('success:', success);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('Error:', e);
      });

  },
  sqs: new AWS.SQS()
});

app.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(err.message);
});

app.start();


const saveToFile = (message) => {
  debugger;
  console.log('saveToFile fired!');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.appendFile(path.resolve(__dirname) + '/zips/decodeMsg.zip', message, (err) => {
      if (err) reject(error);
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

const unzipFile = () => {
  return unzipper.Open.file(path.resolve(__dirname) + '/zips/decodeMsg.zip') // Fails To Read The File Here.
    .then(function (directory) {
      console.log('directory', directory);
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        directory.files[0].stream(password)  // PASSING IN PASSWORD HERE
          .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('readablefile')) // should be XML
          .on('error', reject)
          .on('finish', resolve)
      });
    });
}
```

Update again:

Okay here I am trying to just decrypt the message Body with the following code.

```
    var crypto = require("crypto")
require('./config');

function decrypt(key, data) {
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', key);
        var decrypted = decipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf-8');
        decrypted += decipher.final('utf-8');

        return decrypted;
}

decryptedText = decrypt(process.env.password, process.env.encryptedMessage);
console.log("Decrypted Text: " + decryptedText);
```

However I am getting the following error in the console:

```
      var ret = this._handle.update(data, inputEncoding);
                         ^

TypeError: Bad input string
    at TypeError (native)
    at Decipher.Cipher.update (crypto.js:145:26)
    at decrypt (/Users/dave/Tests/sqs-consumer/app.js:6:34)
```

Comment: How would anyone here know without details on what type of encryption was used? Also, `PUBLISH` doesn't look very encrypted, so it's not the entire body that is encrypted.

Comment: [use decryption](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=decryption+nodejs)

Comment: @robertklep I have added code to my question so you can see everything. Yes as you pointed out PUBLISH is not encrypted so its the string to right of it that is encrypted

Comment: Use any library that can decrypt AES-256 GCM, like crypto.

Comment: So the relevant part of the message body is a password protected ZIP file? Worth to mention that in your question.

Comment: Yes sorry my first question was to focus on the decryption part of the message Body. The message Body is encrypted and crompressed. So in total I need to decrypt and extract the message Body. I have also updated my answer to do show to deal with the decrypt part.